# MeteorJS: How Do I Access The Javascript Console On The Mobile Device

Tags: javascript, meteor, mobile-devices

How do i access the javascript console from the mobile device deployment of a MeteorJS app?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do such things with [ios simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH1-SW1) and Android [Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) for example.

Once you have a device running, you can access the console, DOM inspector etc.

EG with ios simulator - this will open up dev tools:

1) In the simulator, visit a web address in safari.

1) In regular Safari, go to preferences > advanced.

2) In regular Safari preferences, go to Develop > iPhone simulator > yourWebpage

Comment: How can i access the console,  DOM inspector etc on the device? (or was that a typo "can" => "cant").

Comment: @X0r0N  Updated answer with a step by step example for iOS.

Comment: I don't have an iPhone... Does that work if you deploy a MeteorJS standalone app?

Comment: @X0r0N You don't need an iphone, that's the whole point of the simulator. Have you tried it out? It will work. You can run any app in there - localhost or some other non-localhost address. If you try it out, it will work. It's a common practice.

Answer (score 0):

In android development you can use the chrome navigator

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 0):

For iOS:

- Set up developer tools https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html
- Run ios https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile
- When your application is launched in iOS Simulator, launch safari.
- Select the "Develop" menu
- Select "iOS Simulator"

You can now inspect element just like you're used to doing it.

For android follow the instructions here - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Thanks. sure that runs the app in the device and you can hit the local host address with the meteor port. But are you able to do this without the computer that is building the code. For example: I can inspect elements of www.google.com even though the page isn't hosted on my computer. Is it possible for me to go to another computer connect up my phone and access the JS console on that computer? After all it is running a web server? My concern is for security about after I deploy the app as a standalone program on a device. I don't want people to be able to see my code.